# GET Rest API Stuck - Read Timeout Error - JBPM / Kie Server

Tags: java, rest, jbpm, kie-server

I am using **JBPM 7.59**, I have made a headless process on JBPM and running it through Rest API Calls. I have a scenario here in which I got stuck in **GET Rest Api Call** and eventually got **Read Timeout**.

So, my process run smoothly and I reached to that particular point in which my JBPM process call a REST API (implemented in JAVA) to execute particular business and in that business I want some details of that running process instance, so I call below Rest service of JBPM,

**GET**
`/server/admin/containers/{containerId}/processes/instances/{processInstanceId}/nodes`
**Returns all nodes in a specified process instance.**

which obviously means it will return all nodes of specified process instance, but when I call this above service it got stuck and eventually my Rest Client throw **Read time out Exception**.
I have set **30 seconds for Timeout** but this service normally not took more than 35ms in actual case but in this scenario it got stuck, I can understand if this is the scenario for **PUT or POST** calls but I cannot understand why it is happening in **GET** call.

Can anyone please help me on this issue?

TIA

Edited:

Below is the scenario of my JBPM process, where my process stuck. So when I complete this **cas Signing Confirmation** Task from API call, so my next node execute which is **Signing Confirmation** this is basically a Custom REST API call which eventually call to a Java method.

[image: Process of JBPM]

So in that Java method I'm calling below API

**GET** `/server/admin/containers/{containerId}/processes/instances/{processInstanceId}/nodes` **Returns all nodes in a specified process instance**

which eventually got stuck and didn't give me any response.

Below is the java code which I'm using to call above API with (**okHttp**)

```
public static final OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder().connectTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS).readTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS).build();

Request req = new Request.Builder().url("http://localhost:8090/kie-server/services/rest/server/admin/containers/Signing_1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/processes/instances/213/nodes")
.addHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "Basic d2JhZG1pbjp3YmFkbWlu")
.addHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, "application/json")
.addHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json")
.addHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_ENCODING, "gzip, deflate, br");

String response = null;
try (Response res = client.newCall(req).execute()) {
    String responseBody = res.body().string();
    if (res.isSuccessful()) {
        response = responseBody;
    } else {
        int responseCode = res.code();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new JBPMClientException(JBPMClientException.COMMUNICATION_ERROR, e);
}
return response;
```

Got stuck on this line

```
Response res = client.newCall(req).execute()
```

Answer (score 0):

ReadTimeout - read time out - default to 60 seconds.

By default is 60 sec. Is there any reason to set 30 second?

Comment: No there is no any reason to set this timeout but issue is still the same if I set timeout to 60 seconds. My GET call stuck and didn't response.

Comment: Check if there any node stuck or not . Please check database base table nodeinstanceimpl and processinstanceimpl(name can be slightly diff) also and please check the status of that process.

Comment: No, there is only one node which is running at a time and that running node is basically a REST Call which call by JBPM to JAVA, and in that REST Call method I am fetching the details of above mentioned API, and it will stuck there untill it gets timeout. The status of process remains Active. What should I exactly check in those tables ?

Comment: I tried to pass url in rest task data i/p like url " http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server/admin/containers/ww_1.0.1-SNAPSHOT/processes/instances/3/nodes   " and once I start the process from business central  executes successfully , I am not sure your java code what you have implemented  and if you send that code so I can try the same in my local environment.

Comment: I have edited my question, please check